# NextAuth passing unwanted data to user session

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Problem:
In my `[...nextauth].js` file i have callbacks: jwt and session.

jwt callback:

```
async jwt({ token, user }) {
  if (user) {
    token.id = user.id;
    token.username = user.username;
    token.realname = user.realname;
    token.isLogged = user.isLogged;
  }
  return token;
},
```

session callback

```
async session({ session, token }) {
  if (token) {
    session.user.id = token.id;
    session.user.username = token.username;
    session.user.realname = token.realname;
    session.user.isLogged = token.isLogged;
  }
  return session;
},
```

As you can see i specified what i want inside session. But when i am trying to get session (server side with getServerSideProps) with `const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);`
and then console log session i am getting data i specified in token and in session but also i am getting name, email, image that i did not specified, i think is default in nextauth. Now i am getting error serializing .session.user.name (undefined cannot be serialized as JSON) which i did not specified but still getting it. Do you had same problem?

**+EDIT+**

[...nextauth].js

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "AuthMe credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "user" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "pass" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const res = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/login`,
            {
              username: credentials.username,
              password: credentials.password,
            }
          );
          const user = res.data.user;
          console.log("data", user);
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.response.data.error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.username = user.username;
        token.realname = user.realname;
        token.isLogged = user.isLogged;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.username = token.username;
        session.user.realname = token.realname;
        session.user.isLogged = token.isLogged;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

login.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `${req.method} is not allowed.` });
  }
  if (req.body.username === "" || req.body.password === "") {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "No credentials." });
  }

  console.log("username", req.body.username);
  console.log("password", req.body.password);

  // Find user in db
  const isUser = await prisma.authme.findUnique({
    where: {
      username: req.body.username,
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      username: true,
      realname: true,
      password: true,
      isLogged: true,
    },
  });

  if (!isUser) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
  }

  // Check password
  const checkPw = await checkPassword(req.body.password, isUser.password);

  if (!checkPw) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "Passwords do not match" });
  }

  // Separate password
  const { password, ...user } = isUser;

  return res.status(200).json({ user });
}
```

**++EDIT++**
From api/login (prisma)

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "getting_up",
    "realname": "Getting_Up",
    "isLogged": 0
  }
}
```

**+++EDIT+++**
[image: api]

**++++EDIT+++**
I did some testing and even if i get correct data from [...nextauth].js i am still getting user: undefined from `const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);` in `getServerSideProps(context)`
[image: api2]

In docs v3 they say:

```
getSession()
Client Side: Yes
Server Side: Yes
```

But in docs v4 there is this:

```
getSession()
Client Side: Yes
Server Side: No (See: getServerSession()
```

**BUT**(docs v4): NextAuth.js provides a getSession() helper which should be called client side only to return the current active session.

On the server side, this is still available to use, however, we recommend using getServerSession going forward.

With getSession() my code works without error
[image: api3]

My nextauth version is: "next-auth": "^4.22.1", maybe i messed something

Comment: Inside `async session`, try logging `session.user`, what do you see?

Comment: I am getting data that i typed with name, email, image which i did not added and still i am getting them…

Comment: Can you how you are handling the login?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Are you sure prisma is returning only the asked fields? Try console logging the `user` in `res.status(200).json({ user })` before the `return`.

Comment: Yes i am 100%sure

Comment: Upvoted it. Looking at it, but this is quite weird.

Comment: When i used useSession() everything was right no additional data in session, only that i added